# JQuery Rating Plugin for Dynamic Content and Compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am using a JQuery plugin for rating that works in old versions of IE (https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/), everything works fine. The problem is, it is not loading with a dynamically loaded HTML template and I do not want to have to reload the plugin every time there is new content. This seems like a bad approach. Are there any other plugins I could use that work with old browsers and can adapt to dynamic content?

```
<ul class="comments" data-bind="visible:comments, foreach: comments">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

             $('.example-f').barrating({ showSelectedRating:false });
        });
    </script>


    <div class="input select rating-f">
        <select class="example-f">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </div>     
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:
http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/

Light, works great, can be re-enabled and tested with IE7 Emulation.

When you update your content you should call the plugin again to enable new elements.

Comment: do you know if it will work with a dynamically loaded template?

Comment: Yes but not automatically, call the plugin again after your content is updated. See this example http://fiddle.jshell.net/f34kphgy/

Comment: yes Albert, thank you. I will accept your answer. I have another question about this plugin. When I use KnockoutJS to repeat the data in a loop, so the ratings also repeat, when a star is moused over, the rest do not get highlighted. I've edited my question with some code.

Comment: The problem is not a plugin but the way you implement the loop. Script tag should be called only once after you created the content and you should put all repeating content inside li tag when using ul.